# Limitations of Stripe Cloud Code Module for Parse.com?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm using Parse.com's BaaS for data storage and also using their Cloud Code platform for payment processing. Several months ago, I wrote a payment processing script that did work. But now I am noticing differences in class method names and callback structure.

When referring to Parse.com's JS API docs, they referred me to this page:

https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Stripe.html

But it doesn't exist. And the current API docs for Parse's Cloud Code platform doesn't have documentation on their third party modules.

```
The built-in Stripe Cloud Module provides a subset of the functionality available
to Stripe customers. If the feature you are interested in is not supported by this
Cloud Module, you may want to consider writing your own Stripe JavaScript wrapper
as a custom Cloud Module. We suggest looking at Stripe's API Libraries index
for inspiration.
```

Does anyone have any clarification on the limitations of the Stripe Cloud Code Module for Parse.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember the exact version, but it was a late 2011 version of the Stripe API. I got a bit annoyed at the lack of support from Parse and actually built a modified version of Stripe's Node.js API library that would support Parse (a bit of a more complicated endeavor than I was planning). It's currently based on the 4.2.0 version of the Stripe-Node API and should actually be compatible with any version of the Stripe API to date. (Parse actually hard coded the API version).

https://github.com/matthewarkin/stripe-parse

Comment: Thank you so much for making this! I just tested it out and it works perfectly so far.

Comment: Awesome, on a related note, Parse just noted they're shutting down in a year